# Using the chain rule to compute $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{s}}$ given $z=x^2y$, $x=sin(st)$, $y = t^2+s^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, chain-rule

Im familiar with the chain rule when it's as such:
You have a function z=f(x,y), f is differentiable and x=g(t) and y=h(t).

when that's the case I know that we have $\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}\frac{dy}{dt}$

Since $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{s}}$ is not a term in the chain rule, how could I use it to find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, since $x=g(s,t)$ and $y=h(s,t)$ and $z=z(x,y)$ you can say that $$
z=z(s,t)
$$
and use the chain rule to calculate this. You will have
$$
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial s} = \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s} = 2xyt\cos(st) + 2x^2s.
$$
and in this last equation you can substitute $x$ and $y$ for $t$ and $s$.

Comment: I see ! Thank you so much for your help. Just a small comment, I believe that you meant $2xytcos(st)+2x^{2}s$ and not $4x^2s$ but thank you !

Comment: You caught me! :) Don't know if I should edit the typo now.

Comment: @Veliko  Go ahead, do it.